# How to generate huge dynamic test data using jmeter to perform stress testing

Tags: jmeter, stress-testing, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

I need to preform stress testing on Sign Up functionality, where 1000 user should login into the application at same time. It's very difficult to create 1000 test data every time manually in excel sheet and parse to jmeter. Can any one help me out where and how to create script for generating unique test data dynamically using jmeter.

Answer (score 2):

There are [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) which can help you in generating either random or unique data, for example:

- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - returns current thread (virtual user) number

  [image: JMeter ThreadNum Demo]
- __randomString() - generates a string of pseudo-random characters of predefined length

  [image: JMeter Random Demo]
- [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) - returns current time in different formats, by default in milliseconds since start of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

  [image: JMeter Generate Timestamp]

and many others, see [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) guide to learn more about the concept.